# Testing django-pipelines on a dev machine

Tags: django, static, django-pipeline

I would like to test django-pipelines during development (i.e. on a development machine with only django runserver and no production webserver).

Normally during development Django serves static files so long as `DEBUG=True`, but not so if `DEBUG=False`. Thus without a proper webserver it seems I need to keep `DEBUG=True` in my settings. Usually `django-pipelines` does not do compression if `DEBUG=True`, but it can be forced supposedly by setting `PIPELINE_ENABLED=True`. Thus my assumption was that by setting

```
 # local_settings.py
 DEBUG = True   # keep serving static files
 PIPELINE_ENABLED = True   # force django-pipelines to operate
```

I would be in a position to test `django-pipelines` on my dev machine.
I also added

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I ran a collectstatic and the output css file was copied over to my `STATIC_ROOT` (myproj/static_media/static/css/out.css). However Django is not serving this css file. The HTML looks for it

```
<link href="/site_media/static/css/out.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection">
```

but it 404s.

Nevertheless the minute I change `PIPELINE_ENABLED=False` (still `DEBUG=True` etc) and then manually navigate to `/site_media/static/css/out.css` Django serves up the file.

Why isn't this setup working and how can I test `django-pipelines` on a local development machine with nothing but runserver? (this is django 1.8 by the way).

Comment: What is your STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL? Also: why are you hardcoding URL to static file instead of using `{% static %}` tag?

Comment: I'm not hardcoding it, the css link element was generated by `{% stylesheet 'bootstrap' %}` of django-piplines. I was just showing the output the browser sees (i.e. that when pipelines enabled, it is indeed looking for the correct compressed css). As for `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` they are `/site_media/static/` and `/site_media/media/` respectively (things work when `PIPELINES_ENABLED=True` is not forced.

Comment: @fpghost Did you solve it? I have similar problem